# Duplication of properties in Data contract and BAL

Tags: wcf, silverlight, contract

I have a Silverlight Project which passes data using the Data Contract to a WCF service. The WCF method then invokes a BAL class which again has the same properties.  Is there any way to avoid this duplication of properties ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chak,

Depending on your situation this might work for you.  You can share items between projects in Visual Studio.  When adding a new item (C# class in your case), simply add the item as a linked item.  By doing this, the class will only exist in one location.  I wrote a blog post about this a couple months ago.

I hope this helps!

http://www.pagebrooks.com/archive/2008/10/11/sharing-code-between-.net-and-silverlight-platforms.aspx